# How to ignore the ImageMagick warning? @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1744

Tags: imagemagick, image-editing

I want to resize an image on Mac.
I use ImageMagick.

Here code is: `convert eight.png -resize 375X667 resize_eg.png`

There is a warning.

> convert: invalid profile length `eight.png' @
>   warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1744.

According to the [imagemagick org's web page](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=27276),

> It's just a warning. The processing continues. If it worries you, use
>   +profile "*" in the first convert.

I can not get it from **+profile "*"** .

I tried and failed. I think it's easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `+profile "*"` will remove all profiles from the image, for more information about the command see [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile). In your case, you can use it like this:

```
convert eight.png +profile "*" -resize 375X667 resize_eg.png
```

Answer (score 3):

Warnings in ImageMagick can be suppressed with the `-quiet` option. The following should no longer show a warning:

```
convert -quiet eight.png -resize 375X667 resize_eg.png
```

Comment: Note that `-quiet` will "suppress all warning messages" which may result in some warnings being silenced that might be valuable. That said, I've yet to see a single warning from `convert` that's actually worth reading. I don't think `convert` is good enough to validate any files in general and the all the warnings I've seen have always been related to technical issues in input files that convert is able to workaround.

Comment: See `-quiet` at https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php or directly: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quiet